# How do I automatically convert code using os.path to use pathlib?

Tags: python, pathlib

I have some code that uses `os.path.join` and all the other [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) methods. How can I convert it to use [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) objects everywhere.

Is there a more efficient way than grepping for `os.path` and changing every instance?

Comment: Manual job.  APIs are totally different - no way to automatically do that.

Comment: @wim yea, I know. I'm more just hoping someone will answer this question in 5 years, before it gets closed as off-topic for asking for a tool